# Return null if key does not exist in VTL / API Gateway Template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, vtl

The following template returns `''` if the Authorization header is **not** present. How can i get `null` instead? So return `null` if key is not present...

```
{
  "headers" : { 
     "authorization" : "$input.params().header.get('Authorization')" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#if ($variable)` to check if a variable is **not null**

```
#if ($variable) 
   ... do stuff here if the variable is not null
#end
```

In your use case, you can try to put the null check around the authorization header, like this.

```
{
  "headers" : {
     #if( $input.params().header.get('Authorization').toString() != "" ) 
        "authorization" : "$input.params().header.get('Authorization')" 
     #end
  }
}
```